# Change params inside controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I change params inside controller?

When I click the accept it will pass the status is approved but if `diff <= 0` change status to rejected

View

```
<%= link_to 'Accept', friend_path(s, :request => {:status => 'Accepted'}), method: :put  %>
```

into this

```
    if diff <= 0
     req_params[:status] = "Rejected" 
     @request.update(req_params)
    end
end 

private 
 def req_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:status)
 end

end
```

Comment: Is `req_params` is params filtered by strong params? (`require`,`permit`)

Comment: Can you paste the whole controller method? rails doesn't have req_params method

Comment: You want to use `button_to` or a regular form and not `link_to` and pass the parameters in the request body instead of the URL. Using `link_to` with `method:` option should only be really be done when the request has no params like `link_to "Delete", thing, method: :delete`

Comment: Still... It's not clear what is `diff` variable? Can you please post all your controller action code? (I think it's `update` method)

Comment: Where do you take `start` and `end` variables? (I'am asking all of this, because I want to suggest you some really good solution in case of design)

Comment: How do you get `date_params`? I don't see any additional params passed from controller. And what's the logic behind them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158610/discussion-between-antontkachov-and-john).

Comment: Ok. Everything is clear about the code. Right now please explain what is your question? You ask about params edition. But you already have a code `req_params[:status] = "Rejected" `. Doesn't it work as you expect it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To modify your status param, you need to do the following:

```
params[:request][:status] = 'Rejected' 

or

req_params[:request][:status] = 'Rejected'
```

Because your request take params like this:

```
Parameters => { some_param => 'Something', required => { permited1 => 'bla', 
                                                     permited2 => 'bla2',
                                                    ... } }
```

I hope that helps you